# how to send a URL to messaging apps like whatsapp, hike,ect with hide

Tags: android

I am new to the android, I want to send the image and URL to messaging apps like whatsapp, hike, Messager, ect. First, I am using fireballs App Invites for this, but it supports only mail and SMS app. I want to use all apps. Is it possible to send a link with masking like links in web sites. [In this image when we click on install it opens url, like this I want to send in whatsapp hike also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Pdx.png) For example: http://www.pupsor.com/cute-baby-puppys-14193.html this is my image url. Sorry for my English. please help me.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the apps you mentioned have a different way of receiving data. Please check the documentation for each of the apps to learn more.

As an example, [here is the documentation for WhatsApp](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/pl/android/28000012).

Also, you will usually be able to pass a text String, without html formatting or images. Still, depends on the app.